# How to test exceptions using a data provider in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

PHPUnit has a very useful feature [`@dataProvider`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.examples.DataTest.php), that allows to test multiple cases of a method. It also has another cool annotation -- [`@expectedException`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest2.php) to ensure the application throws a correct `Exception` at a defined place.

I'm currently testing a method against multiple edge cases and would like to combine these two features like this (not working code):

```
class TestMyClass
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideDataForFoo
     */
    public function testFoo($paramBar, $paramBuz, $expected)
    {
        $myObject = new MyClass();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $myObject->foo($paramBar, $paramBuz));
    }
    public function provideDataForFoo()
    {
        return [
            ['expected lorem', 'bar lorem', 'buz lorem'],
            ['expected ipsum', 'bar ipsum', 'buz ipsum'],
            ['expected exception', 'bar invalid argument', 'buz invalid argument'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**Is possible / How to use `@expectedException` as one of the cases, when using `@dataProvider`?**

Comment: If only one set is supposed to throw an exception, you should add a separate test for that. That test should call the code that actually throws the exception as `assertEquals()` will not do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHPUnit doesn't provide this combination. But this can be implemented with a simple trick:

1. **basic solution**

Separate test methods for normal and exception testing.

```
class TestMyClass
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideDataForFoo
     */
    public function testFoo($paramBar, $paramBuz, $expected)
    {
        $myObject = new MyClass();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $myObject->foo($paramBar, $paramBuz));
    }
    public function provideDataForFoo()
    {
        return [
            ['expected lorem', 'bar lorem', 'buz lorem'],
            ['expected ipsum', 'bar ipsum', 'buz ipsum'],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideDataForFooException
     */
    public function testFooException($paramBar, $paramBuz, $expectedException)
    {
        $myObject = new MyClass();
        $this->expectException($expectedException);
        $myObject->foo($paramBar, $paramBuz);
    }
    public function provideDataForFooException()
    {
        return [
            ['expected exception', 'bar invalid argument', '\My\Exception\Fully\Qualified\Name'],
        ];
    }
}
```

2. **extended solution**

a. One test method and using the [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) API.

We have only one test method. The data provider method returns an array, where to elements for the `$expected` test method input can be `Exceptions`. If the `$expected` is an `Exception` we handle this case with `expectException(...)`, otherwise as a "normal" test case.

b. One test method and using an "exception" flag.

Theoretically a method can `return` an `Exception`. To consider this case we have to introduce a flag like "testItForException" and provide this information to the test method. It also can be a further element, e.g. `exception`, in the array returned by the data provider method (and then in the test method: `if(! (empty($exception)) { test it as normal } else {expect exception})`).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the annotation you can also use `$this->setExpectedExceptionRegExp()` with the arguments

```
$exceptionName — mixed (class name or exception instance)
$exceptionMessageRegExp — string (optional regular expression)
$exceptionCode — integer (optional exception code)
```

**Note:** The old `setExpectedException()` method has been deprecated in PHPUnit 5.2

This means, you can pass an exception class name via data provider. If it is not empty, call `setExpectedExceptionRegExp()`

Another advantage of the method over the annotation is that you can be more specific about *where* the exception is expected, if you don't call the method at the beginning of the test.